# Laravel maat excell unable to access stored csv file

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Laravel 5.6.39

Matt Excel 3.1

I am able to store the csv file on storage/app/public directory using

```
$excel = (new ReportExport($results))->store('public/' . $fileName, 'local');
```

updated my code to 3.1

```
$excel = Excel::store(new ReportExport($results), 'public/' . $fileName, 'local');
```

I also created the simlink uisng

```
php artisan storage:link
```

as described in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk)

and able to get the correct link to file using

```
$path = asset('storage/app/public/' . $fileName);
```

but if I am trying to use this link in a button to download the file, I am getting 404 error.

Comment: `404` means route doesn't exists!

Comment: @Iftikharuddin I can confirm, the file is getting saved in correct folder with correct data.

Comment: can you show your URL?

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi `http://localhost/mysite/public/storage/app/public/49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv` something like this.

Comment: try like this: http://localhost/mysite/storage/49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi getting same error.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I updated my code to 3.1 for storing file, now too able to store the file correctly, getting correct url, file permission now 777, still  unable to get it download with button click, showing 404.

Comment: let me create one demo in my local server.

Comment: try this: localhost/mysite/public/storage/49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi Are you able to down load the file using this url?

Comment: yes. This worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path will be

```
http://localhost/mysite/public/storage/49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/mysite/public/storage/app/public/49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv
```

so the url should be created by     `$path = asset('storage/' . $fileName);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have created simlink then this should work.

> localhost/mysite/public/storage/49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv

Comment: Let me make a separate installation and test as for my current installation it does not seems to be working, have you used the same code I have posted?

Comment: Yes. You can also check by manually storing one file in storage/app/public/ folder and create simlink to access using above url

Comment: also confirm whether you have a file named 49c486c6dc126abc4224b606706f010b.csv

Comment: File name correct, I am able to see and open the files, it is just the url, for which I am facing problem.

Comment: have you checked the permission assinged to that folder?

Comment: I just tested it with fresh installation and getting same 404 error!!!!

Comment: let me share the code gist and you can see it , may be we can get a better idea on it, I will share Export class code and controller method code of the fresh installation I created.

Comment: please have a look on gist https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/ad091f316d976a93b3c19e0974ae6ccc