# Laravel file uploading goes wrong when I remove the quicklink to the storage/images folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with fileuploading(images). my script somehow can read my articles and put them on the show page but doesn't want to insert the images into the folder.

Everything in the database works fine, you can see everything getting submitted but when inserting images into the storage/cover_images folder it doesn't put them inside. after I removed the quick link(PHP artisan storage:link) to the storage folder it didn't work anymore. I can't add it back because I work with colleagues who pull the project from GitHub and the quick links are local so otherwise, it will only work on my computer.

TO BE CLEAR:

The only thing i want is that my images will be inserted into the public/storage/cover_images folder.

my site doesnt give back errors and inserts everything into the database. the only thing that needs to be fixed is my images into the public/storage/cover_images folder.

**in my ArticleController:**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){

        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName(); 

        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        $extension =  $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() .'.'. $extension;

        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('/public/storage/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);

    }else{

        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';

    }
```

**show.blade.php(which works fine):**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="artikelfoto marginauto col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-3 mb-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$artikel->cover_image}}" style="width:100%">
                <p style="font-size:.75em; color:#b4b4b4">{{$artikel->source}}</p>
            </div>
```

**the public folder with paths:**

[image]

**database(you can see everything gets inserted):**

[image]

does anyone faced this problem before? any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do not know why you have deleted that symlink, use `php artisan storage:link` and try again and let me know.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the thing is when i push the project on github it doesnt push the symlink because you create the symlink locally

Comment: Then you can run this command in your server through ssh.

Comment: Sorry but i looked up SSH and it really looks confusing to me and i think there should be much easier solutions

Comment: If you are not pushing your vendor folder and images to server and creating those separately in server, then why it is wrong to create symlink in server?

Comment: to make things clear, i dont think its wrong but i have no idea how to do it and the documentation looks hard to implement

Comment: Are you able to login through ssh and enter to your laravel directory?

Comment: sorry, but i dont even know what ssh is . so im pretty sure im not even using it at the moment

Comment: Oh!, how you are pushing your code to your server?

Comment: by gitbash / git gui

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883389/laravel-maat-excell-unable-to-access-stored-csv-file) I was facing similar issue.

Comment: so how you are login into your server git repo?

Comment: my problem is not server sided. the thing is you cannot push a symlink so my colleagues are pulling everything but the symlink. so for me it will work but not for my colleagues

Comment: also there should be a problem with the path. because if i copy the full link to the image it will display on my site

Comment: I can only wish good luck to you now, as I am perhaps unable to understand your problem or unable to explain my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have ssh access then simply create a route.so you can hit this command simply by hitting url

```php
Route::get('/artisan/storage', function() {
    $command = 'storage:link';
    $result = Artisan::call($command);
    return Artisan::output();
})
```

Comment: is this the exact piece of code i need because i dont use /artisan/storage but i use /public/storage?

Comment: just copy paste then hit this url. its make a link public/storage

Comment: it returns this: The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Comment: firstly delete storage folder link inside public then hit

Comment: i've done that, it said successfully created link but is it using a symlink again because if i push this to github it will probably not pull it when my colleagues try

Comment: when someone download your code he need to again make a link